# CSS bug span overflow from div

Tags: css

Navigate to the **clients** page and you should see links and email addresses overflowing out of their containing div tags given the class 'client' For example:

```
<div class="client">
<span class="delete">
<span class="name">
<span class="address">
<span class="municipal">
<span class="county">
<span class="phone">
<p class="email">
<span class="url">
<strong>www:</strong>
<a href="http://www.edjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjju.salford.ac.uk">
</span>
</div>
```

is there anyway to prevent the string of text inside the span element for email and website leaving the div make it run on a new line continuously underneath? The solution needs to be in order so the page can CSS can be validated by the W3C.

Comment: here you go, sorry has been edited

Comment: ideally both if possible

Comment: I would have though there was a simple CSS solution, for example setting a fixed width on the span elements.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? Also your website doesn't work. Even when you try and login, you aren't given access to the Clients page.

Comment: @tw16 Interesting; I can access the Clients page. Maybe it works with cookies?

Comment: @tw16 It does work in FF12 if you enable cookies, I just tested.

Answer (score 2):

write like this:

```
a{
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: I need a cross browser solution will this cover all browsers?

Comment: Yes it's support all browsers.

Comment: does not comply with the the W3C CSS Validation Service

Comment: @user1392324 Don't mind the CSS validator; it's not up to date. According to [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap), `word-wrap` is now officially called `overflow-wrap`, and "For legacy reasons, UAs may also accept ‘word-wrap’ as an alternate name for the ‘overflow-wrap’ property." But the validator doesn't recognise `overflow-wrap` either.

Comment: +1 and @user1392324: And as you can see here, it has good browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap